# Get the index of li with dynamic class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a menu on a OnePage Website. On scroll the .active class does move to that listitem thats in focus. Or by clicking the menuitems the page scrolls to its section.
Now I want to get the index of the active listitem to do something.

```
var index = $("#navigation>li.active").index();
```

or check if on special listitems is active

```
if ($('.listitem1').hasClass('active')) {
   $('.content').on('click', function() { 
      alert("do it"); 
      return false;       
   });
};
```

both does not work. Why?

Comment: You should swap your bottom function around so that you call the `onclick` FIRST, then check to see if it has the class

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) because: https://jsfiddle.net/xfcu80zr/

Comment: What doesn't work? What are *".content"* and *".listitem1"*? How are these elements nested in your HTML?

Comment: .conent is simly a test element to click on, .listitem1 is the class of the first menuitem. This is only for testing if the class ".active" was recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Try this basic example

```js
$('li').on('click', function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
   $('span').text($(this).index());
  } else {
  alert('no active class found');
  }
});
```

```css
li:hover {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The clicked element with an active class's index is: <span></span></p>
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li class="active">second - with .active</li>
<li>third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to check a dynamic class not a click. With click the index is no problem. The active class was added by an other plugin.

Comment: @AchimUdo Check my answer again. Does that help?

Comment: And do you have more than one instance of an element with the class of `.listitem1` ??